# Which element do I change so as to add a border image between posts?

Tags: css

The template I am using for my site (under development) is identical to [this one](http://www.lucidpictures.co.za/).

I'd like to add a border image between posts (In this case between "Let You Know Music video" and "Land of Hope") but not after the last post.

Which element do I edit ([css source](http://www.informationarchitects.jp/en/wp-content/themes/iA3%201.2.2/style.css?v=1)) to make this happen?

Do I edit the `containsArticles` class? `dt containsArticles`?

I've tried adding a `background: url(/path/to/border-image.gif) no-repeat center bottom;` to either element and cannot make it work. Ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a rule already in there actually:

line: 1449

```
.containsArticles dd, #containsTwoosers, #screen > header, #screen > footer > nav > ul, .archives #content fieldset, .index #content .G6, .single #comments form {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhSAABAIAAAP///2ZmZiH5BAEHAAAALAAAAABIAAEAAAINDG54kLwNn1TU1XhXAQA7);
}
```

The reason why it's not on the last child is because of this rule:

line: 682

```
.containsArticles dd:last-child {
    background: transparent !important;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

The rule preventing this default behavior is

line:1418

```
.index .containsArticles dd {
    background: transparent !important;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

all in `style.css`

completely removing that last rule will get you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `.index .containsArticles dd` selector, which already exists on the demo site you linked.

Also if your using a background image, make sure you give that same element some bottom padding for the background image to appear in.

```
.index .containsArticles dd {
  background: url("path/to/image.png") no-repeat center bottom transparent;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.containsArticles>dd{yourStyleHere}
```